# Pymodbus - Someimes runs & sometimes runtime Error

Tags: java, python-3.x, modbus, pymodbus

I am using RS485 to USB Converter for commmunication.
I am trying to read input registers but sometimes its result comes and sometimes not.
I am using pymodbus-2.3.0 external library & I use pycharm for the code.

```
import logging
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

from pymodbus.register_read_message import ReadInputRegistersResponse


logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM3',
                      baudrate=9600, timeout=1, parity='N', stopbits=2)
print(client.connect())
client.debug_enabled()

log.debug("Read Holding registers")
response = client.read_holding_registers(0, 10, unit=0x01)

if not response.isError():
    '''isError() method implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above'''

    print(response.registers)  # Note.

else:
    # Handle Error.
    print('Unable to read or there is the connection problem.')

    # print(response.getRegister(0));  #This returns value of only one

    client.close()
```

In the output due to logging u may watch difference in it.

output:

```
C:\Users\meet2\PycharmProjects\Modbus\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/meet2/PycharmProjects/Modbus/o.py
DEBUG:root:Read holding registers
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x70 0xd
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
True
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x1 0x4 0x14 0x0 0xf 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x62 0x8f
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Getting Frame - 0x4 0x14 0x0 0xf 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x5a 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Response[ReadInputRegistersResponse: 4]
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame advanced, resetting header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Adding transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
[15, 0, 90, 90, 90, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\meet2\PycharmProjects\Modbus\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/meet2/PycharmProjects/Modbus/o.py
True
DEBUG:root:Read holding registers
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x70 0xd
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Incomplete message received, Expected 25 bytes Recieved 5 bytes !!!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x1 0x4 0x14 0x0 0xf
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x1 0x4 0x14 0x0 0xf
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Unable to read or there is the connection problem.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

your help will be appreciated.

Here is my java code which runs perfectly

```
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.facade.ModbusSerialMaster;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.Modbus;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.ModbusException;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.procimg.Register;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.util.SerialParameters;

class ModbusMaster
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /* The important instances of the classes mentioned before */
        ModbusSerialMaster serialMaster = null; // the connection
        
        /* Variables for storying the parameters */
        String portname = "USB3"; // the name of the serial port to be used
        int unitID = 1 ; // the unit identifier we will be talking to
        int startingRegister = 1; // the reference, where to start reading from
        int registerCount = 10; // the count of the input registers to read
        Register[] slaveResponse = new Register[registerCount];
    
        try 
        {
            /* Setup the serial parameters */
            SerialParameters parameters = new SerialParameters();
            parameters.setPortName(portname);
            parameters.setBaudRate(9600);
            parameters.setDatabits(8);
            parameters.setParity("None");
            parameters.setStopbits(1);
            parameters.setEncoding(Modbus.SERIAL_ENCODING_RTU);
            parameters.setEcho(false);
            parameters.setTimeout(5);
            
            /* Open the connection */
            serialMaster = new ModbusSerialMaster(parameters);
            serialMaster.connect();
    
        } 
        
        catch (Exception exception) 
        {
            System.out.println("Not Run");
            exception.printStackTrace();
            
        }
    
        /* Read the first four holding registers */
        try 
        {
            slaveResponse = serialMaster.readMultipleRegisters(unitID, startingRegister, registerCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < slaveResponse.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("reg" + i + " = " + slaveResponse[i]);
            }
        } 
        
        catch (ModbusException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Close the connection */
        serialMaster.disconnect();
    
    }
}
```

it gives output like

```
reg0=15
reg1=90
reg2=15
reg3=15
reg4=14
reg5=18
reg6=85
reg7=45
reg8=10
reg9=11
```

Comment: You are likely having a hardware issue, there is nothing wrong with your code. Double check your wiring and make sure you have a GND cable if you are using battery powered devices. There might be a problem on the slave firmware and/or hardware. If you need further help on those topics feel free to edit your question to add more details

Comment: But when i run java code it gives perfect output everytime.

Comment: Hello Yash. That's the kind of thing you should include in your question. If you add your Java code maybe somebody will be able to notice any problems comparing to your Python code. As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with your Python code...

Comment: Hello Yash, nice edit. I see three obvious differences: you are using two stop bits in Python and one in your Java code, why is that? Two: you are reading input registers with Java but holding registers with Pythons, there might be something going on with the slave... And three: you have 5 seconds timeout versus 1 second, that can also make a difference depending on the slave (but I don't think that should be the main culprit here).

Comment: When i ruuned it in raspberrypi,it succesfully runned, may be problem was with windows.